# find -maxdepth 0 not returning me any output

Tags: find

I am trying to understand how to use `find -maxdepth 0` option.

I have the below directory structure.

```
--> file1
--> parent
          --> child1
                   --> file1
                   --> file2
          --> child2
                   --> file1
                   --> file2
          --> file1
```

Now, I execute my `find` command as below.

```
find ./parent -maxdepth 0 -name "file1"
find ./ -maxdepth 0 -name "file1"
find . -maxdepth 0 -name "file1"
```

With none of the above `find` commands, **file1** gets returned.

From man page of `find`, I see the below information.

> -maxdepth 0
>                  means only apply the tests and actions to the command line arguments.

I searched for some examples with `-maxdepth 0` option and couldn't find any proper example.

My `find` version is,

```
find --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2
```

Can someone please provide me some pointers on which cases `-maxdepth 0` option would be useful?

**EDIT**

When I execute the below command, I get the **file1** getting listed twice. Is this intended to work this way?

```
find . file1 -maxdepth 1 -name "file1"
./file1
file1
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Let us suppose that we have `file1` in the current directory.  Then:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 0 -name "file1"
$ find . file1 -maxdepth 0 -name "file1"
file1
```

Now, let's look at what [the documentation](https://ss64.com/bash/find.html) states:

> `-maxdepth 0`
> means only apply the tests and actions to the command line arguments.

In my first example above,
only the directory **`.`** is listed on the command line.  Since **`.`** does not have the name `file1`, nothing is listed in the output.  In my second example above, both **`.`** and `file1` are listed on the command line,
and, because `file1` matches `-name "file1"`, it was returned in the output.

In other words, `-maxdepth 0` means do **not** search directories or subdirectories.  Instead, only look for a matching file among those explicitly listed on the command line.

In your examples, only directories were listed on the command line and none of them were named `file1`.  Hence, no output.

In general, many files and directories can be named on the command line. 
For example, here we try a `find` command
with nine files and directories on the command line:

```
$ ls
d1  file1  file10  file2  file3  file4  file5  file6  file7
$ find d1 file1 file10 file2 file3 file4 file5 file6 file7 -maxdepth 0 -name "file1"
file1
```

#### Overlapping paths

Consider:

```
$ find . file1 -maxdepth 0 -iname file1
file1
$ find . file1 file1 -maxdepth 0 -iname file1
file1
file1
$ find . file1 file1 -maxdepth 1 -iname file1
./file1
file1
file1
```

`find` will follow each path specified on the command line and look for matches even if the paths lead to the same file, as in `. file`,
or even if the paths are exact duplicates, as in `file1 file1`.

Comment: thanks. But how could I pass some file names on command line?

Comment: Good point.  See my updated answer.  You can put as many as you want before the first test.  For example: `find * -maxdepth 0 -name "file1"`.  The `*` will list every file in the current directory on the command line.

Comment: @Ramesh Answer updated again with, I hope, better explanation and examples.

Comment: thanks again. I updated my question with more details from your latest update.

Comment: @Ramesh I cannot find it documented but I see the same behavior you do: `find` looks at each path on the command line and reports matches on each one even if they are duplicates.

Comment: no worries. It was a very good answer with good crisp examples. I couldn't find a single place with an example for `-maxdepth 0` option. I will wait for some more time before I accept the answer.

Comment: @tedly: Please look at context when you are editing. The above post said "For example, here we try a `find` command with 11 files and directories on the command line", and you changed the example command, but not the "11".

Answer (score 3):

If you want to non-recursively find files (not directories) inside a directory  use:

```bsh
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "file1"
# ./file1
```

`-maxdepth 0` **will not search**. It will only try to match among the file/directory names that you have provided as arguments in `find`.

E.g. in the above statement, using a `maxdepth` value of `0`, would try to match `file1` to `.` which does not match.

**However,** passing `*` instead of `.` in combination with `-maxdepth 0` would make bash replace `*` with list of files in current dir which would return a match.

Answer (score 0):

Usage:

John1024 gave good examples, **how** to use `-maxdepth 0`, so I only add information of **when** to use it:

Well, what's the reason for `-maxdepth 0`? If you know the name, you may just issue the command

```
ls file-*
```

Well, it might not be the name, what you're searching for.

Example:

```
touch file-{1..3}
echo "1" > file-1
touch -d @0 file-2

find * -maxdepth 0 -name "file-*" \( -size 1k -o -mtime +10000 \) -ls 
   669266     12 -rw-rw-r--   1 stefan   stefan          2 Mai  4 20:57 file-1
   669270      8 -rw-rw-r--   1 stefan   stefan          0 Jan  1  1970 file-2
```

I create 3 files with the name pattern file-*. Then I add some content to no. 1, reset the date for no. 2 and leave no. 3 as is.

Now I search for files of 1k (no.1) or age > roughly 30 years in maybe 1000s of files. For the example, just among 3 files.

But find * searches every file in the current directory, hence the somewhat alien man page jargon, of "starting point" instead of just speaking about directories. I guess the powerful filter features of find had led to the decision, to search for files, of which you know where they're located (the $PWD), but you can't easily filter for other attributes with standard shell tools.