# find doesn't work when run from remote script

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, ubuntu, find

I have following line in a script:

```
find ~ Templates -maxdepth 0 -type d -empty
```

which works fine, as expected. However when I copy my script to samba share and run it from there (`bash myscript.sh`), `find` doesn't find the directory:

```
find: ‘Templates’: No such file or directory
```

$PATH variables are the same, in strace I couldn't find reason for this either.

Anybody knows why find behaves this way ? Is it a bug or am I not using `find` command as I am supposed to ?

using Ubuntu 19.10 and bash 5.0

Comment: Is there a `Templates` subdirectory visible from the point where you are running the script?

Comment: @jesse_b that's normal - the error message does indeed include those paired quotes

Comment: with find command no-I get same error, but when I do 'ls ~/Templates' from same remote directory I can see it, only find command doesn't see it

Comment: But you haven't used `~/Templates` in your command

Comment: no, because Templates is directory I am searching for in a '~' or user's home directory

Comment: If you're looking for `Templates` in the user's home directory then see [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/573262/100397).

Comment: >  _because Templates is directory I am searching for in a '~' or user's home directory_   you should say it in your question cause at the moment noone knows what is your goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the message `find: ‘Templates’: No such file or directory` because there is no Templates subdirectory

- either - from the point you are running the script
- or - in the directory to which some un-mentioned `cd` in your script has switched

I'm wondering if this is all a typo and you meant `~/Templates`. Either way, you should not use `~` in a script but instead use `"$HOME"`, so the resulting path would be `"$HOME/Templates"`.

Comment: I tried use $HOME instead of ~, no difference, command 'find ~ *' run from samba directory returns content of current samba location, not my home directory, which I don't think is correct, since I asked for content of home directory, not the current one with 'find . *'

Comment: @mauekunak of course `find ~ *` will list the contents of your home directory and then the current directory. For some reason you seem to be ignoring the directory separator `/`.

Comment: that was it, I was missing slash character the whole time, now it works, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

What makes you believe that samba has the same environmental variables as linux?

Use real/full path to directory you want to search as `~` is not directory, it's probaly empty - that's why find treats `Templates` as path not search pattern (`find: ‘Templates’: No such file or directory`).

Can you start shell in your samba directory and see what it is with `$ pwd`? You can also check whole environment with `$ set`;

[Using Samba book variables chapter](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/network_administration_guides/using_samba_book/ch04_01_07.html) says that home directory is `%H` not `~`.

small experiment:

```
$ ls -l | grep -E '^d'  # to show there is 1 directory (tmp), which is not empty but doesnt have `Templates`
drwxr-xr-x 2  user  group  24576 Mar 16 16:16 tmp
```

```
$ find Templates -maxdepth 0 -type d -empty  # as if <path> (`~`) was empty
find: Templates: No such file or directory

$ find tmp Templates -maxdepth 0 -type d -empty  # as if `~` was `tmp`
find: Templates: No such file or directory
```

Either `~` is empty (first `find ...` with "empty" path.) or you don't have `Templates` in searched path (second `find`).

```
$ touch Templates
$ find tmp Templates -maxdepth 0 -type d -empty  # as if `~` was `tmp`

$ rm Templates; mkdir Templates
$ find tmp Templates -maxdepth 0 -type d -empty  # as if `~` was `tmp`
Templates
```

---

If

> Templates is directory I am searching for in a '~' or user's home directory

then

```
$ find ~ -maxdepth 1 -type d -empty -name Templates
~/Templates
```

Should solve the problem.

`-maxdepth 0` only applies the tests and actions to the command line arguments (according to [man find](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find); check also [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162411/find-maxdepth-0-not-returning-me-any-output/162413#162413))

Comment: In many shells `~` represents the user's `"$HOME"` directory. And `%H` is for the server-side configuration file, not the client.

Answer (score 0):

"no, because Templates is directory I am searching for in a '~' or user's home directory"

```
find ~ -maxdepth 0 -type d -empty -name Templates
```